# Building 32bit binary for ARM on 64bit CentOS

Tags: gcc, arm

It seems that gcc doesn't accept -m32 option for ARM target. I am not sure how gcc behaves on 64bit Linux, but does it automatically generate 32bit binaries if gcc is of ELF32 running on 64bit Linux?

If so, is there any workaround?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a cross-compiler to compile for ARM from your host running either x86 or x86_64, the reason being your host and target are 2 totally independent architectures.

The cross compiler would usually be configured to output only a 32-bit or 64-bit binary for ARM (not both). Most ARM device applications make use of only 32-bit and so using an arm cross-compiler without any extra arguments would build 32-bit binaries.

Toolchains have other -m flags to specify machine type such as armv7, arm cortex a-8, etc. for further optimization. You need to look at the documentation of the  ARM cross compiler.

As for getting the correct toolchain which works for your target and runs under CentOS, it is better to start at the website of the vendor of the target device.

The -m32 option provided by the x86_64 version of gcc makes gcc compile 32-bit binaries instead of 64-bit since the x86 instruction set and the x86_64 (AMD64 or Intel EMT64) are quite similar. Especially the fact that it allows executing 32-bit instructions in 64-bit mode quite easily.

Comment: I am using a gcc customized by an SoC vendor that no longer supports the gcc. The vendor said that the gcc wouldn't work correctly on 64bit Linux. So I am looking for a workaround.

Comment: Most vendor gcc binaries for the toolchain are compiled to be run on a 32-bit host (i.e. x86). And 64-bit linux hosts support running 32-bit binaries quite smoothly. The actual commands invoked by the gcc cross-toolchain would be the same independent of the host being 32-bit or 64-bit. I myself have been using MIPS and ARM cross compiler toolchains on both 32-bit and 64-bit hosts unchanged without any issues.

Comment: Have you seen difference in file size between a binary built on 32bit host and one on 64bit?

Comment: No there should not be any such obvious difference in file size for the same source code.

Comment: Looks like I haven't given good directives to the preprocessor. I must check it. Thanks a lot!